# Important Step in the proof of Chern-Gauß-Bonnet

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am currently reading the proof of the Chern-Gauß-Bonnet theorem by [Chern](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969302?origin=crossref). In one of the last steps I don't understand how we obtain the Euler characteristic with Stokes. I know that he uses the Poincaré-Hopf theorem to obtain the Euler characteristic from the index of the vector field, but where do we get the mapping degree that gives the index?

So, we have a closed, riemannian manifold $M$ with $dim(M)=n=2p$ and the unit tangent bundle $\pi:UT(M)\to M$.
Furthermore we have the integrand of the Gauß-Bonnet integral $pf(\Omega/2\pi)$. This is a closed form on $M$ and we can pull this back to $UT(M)$ to get a exact form $\pi^*(pf(\Omega/2\pi))=d\Pi$. Now Chern takes a continuous unit vector field $X$ on $M$ with a singular point in $0\in M$. This vector field defines a n-dimensional submanifold $V^n$ in $UT(M)$, I guess by taking the graph of the vector field.

First Question: He says that $\partial V^n=\chi(M) \mathcal{S}^{n-1}_0 $, where $\mathcal{S}^{n-1}_0 $ is the fiber over the singularity of the vector field and $\chi(M)$ is the Euler characteristic of $M$. Why is this true?

Second Question: In the calculation we have
\begin{align*}
\int_M pf(\Omega/2\pi)=\int_{V^n}\pi|_{V^n}^*(pf(\Omega/2\pi))=\int_{V^n}d\Pi\overset{?}{=}\chi(M)\int_{\mathcal{S}_0^{n-1}}\Pi.
\end{align*}
In the equality with the (?) he uses Stokes. But why do we get $\chi(M)$? From Poincaré-Hopf we know that $\chi(M)=ind_X(0)=deg(X)$. But
\begin{align*}
deg(X)\int_{\mathcal{S}_0^{n-1}}\Pi=\int_{\partial\overline{B_r(0)}}X^*(\Pi)
\end{align*}
if I understood the mapping degree correct. So I wonder where the RHS is hidden in the above computation.

Can someone give me a hint as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's certainly not necessary to do so, Chern takes the vector field $X$ to have its *only* singularity at $0\in M$. (You could do the standard proof of taking a generic vector field with singularities at $p_1,\dots,p_k$, remove small balls centered at each of the $p_i$, and then apply Stokes's Theorem to the corresponding remaining part of $V$.) Then, either way, the answer to your first question is to apply the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem.

The equality in your second question is a direct application of the statement in your first. Your argument with the degree theorem is, indeed, a justification of his original assertion.

Comment: So before using Stokes we could pull back $d\Pi$ with the vector field, then interchange the pull back and $d$ and then use Stokes. This would give me the integral over the boundary of the ball around the singularity. The rest is then the formula for the mapping degree and Poincaré-Hopf. Is this the the right way to do it in more detail?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would write it up.